# Alternative proof of Cayley's theorem works only for abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-homomorphism

I am trying to prove Cayley's theorem in a way which avoids any particular maps from $G$ to a group of permutations on any particular set (contrary to the standard way of proving it, which involves associating every element $a$ with a permutation $ax$ as $x$ spans $G$). Here's an outline for Abelian groups of non-prime order:

1. If groups $X$ and $Y$ are each isomorphic to a group of permutations, $X \times Y$ is also isomorphic to a group of permutations. (this is generally true for non-Abelian groups as well)
2. We use strong induction on the order of $G$, assuming that all groups of order $(<k)$ are isomorphic to groups of permutations: the case for $1$ is trivially true.
3. By the [basis theorem for finite Abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Classification), every finite Abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to the product of cyclic subgroups (of $G$). Thus, by the inductive hypothesis, and $(1)$, we reach the desired conclusion. (I guess this fails when $G$ is of prime order)

However, the same approach fails when I try to apply it to non-Abelian groups. I have tried using the same techniques used in the proof of the basis theorem for finite Abelian groups. That entailed constructing a group $\langle x_1\rangle\times\langle x_2\rangle\times...\times\langle x_n\rangle$ of all or some elements of $G$ (I have also briefly tried selecting elements of prime power order). My approach was to prove the theorem from the fact that if a group $S$ is isomorphic to a group of permutations, then any subgroup of $S$ is also. So if we manage to find a group bigger than $G$ that satisfies the statement, we are done. But the one thing where this approach seems to fail is in proving that $\langle x_1\rangle\times\langle x_2\rangle\times...\times\langle x_n\rangle$ actually contains an isomoporphic copy of $G$. If you try to simply associate each product $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ with he result of multiplying all the elements in $G$, that does not generally produce a homomorphism precisely because of the non-Abelian nature of $G$:

if $f$ is the function that associates every element of $\langle x_1\rangle\times\langle x_2\rangle\times...\times\langle x_n\rangle$ with the result of multiplying all the individual elements of $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ in $G$,

$$f((x_1, ..., x_n)\times (y_1, ..., y_n)) = x_1y_1...x_ny_n$$
which is not generally equal to
$$f(x_1, ..., x_n)\cdot f(y_1, ..., y_n) = x_1...x_ny_1...y_n$$

So my question is, is there a way of extending this construction-less approach to proving Cayley's theorem to all groups or is there no way of doing so? I think it *might* just be possible to do so because the basis theorem used in the Abelian approach has stronger implications than are needed for proving just this theorem. If it were possible to prove that $G$ is just equal to *some* product of proper subgroups, we would be mostly done. Only the prime-ordered cases would remain.

Comment: I just realized a mistake in my approach is that you can't just use non-prime order groups in the induction, so my first approach fails in the respect. But the question remains - is the idea plausible?

Comment: "which avoids any map from $G$ to group of permutations" - but you still use groups of permutations? So where is the difference in the end? Why should we avoid standard methods?

Comment: Notice "any *particular*" map. I do, of course, use general maps, when I assume they exist. For instance, in proving (1).

Comment: Since the theorem states that $G$ is *isomorphic* to a group of permutations, we can't avoid maps altogether, nor was that ever my goal. My goal was of avoiding a particular way of associating the elements of $G$ with permutations. For example, in the usual proof, you take the elements of $G$, say the element $a$ and associate (map) it with (to) the function $f_a(x) = ax$, which happens to be a permutation. But that is not only a map to a particular set ($G$), but also very specific map.

Comment: OK, but still I don't see why we shouldn't use the left multiplication map. It's so nice :)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Agreed, but the right multiplication map is even nicer, because it leads to a right action, which is of course far superior!!!

Comment: Well there are other nice maps like $f(a) \mapsto g_a(x) = a^{ord(a) - 1}x$ for example. I guess I don't like how the actual statement of the theorem is quite a bit bigger than what we reduce it to. It could instead be "Any group has an automorphism with this specific action" and the fact that that means that any group is a group of permutations. Of course, the left multiplication map is also elegant (more elegant than, say, right multiplication)